# Automatic Tool to add JavaScript support for IPAD safari?

Tags: java, javascript, ipad

I was requested to test the feasibility of supporting other browser beside IE (mainly safari on IPAD) on large J2ee application,
Supporting Safari will require conversion of significant amount of complex JavaScript code,
Is there any good tool that can help converting large amount of JavaScript code?
Is there any Tool that can analyze and point on IE specific JavaScript code?

Comment: Safari will come prebuilt with loads more support for native JS that IE declines to include. What isn't working for you in Safari that does in IE?

Comment: Can you exhibit examples of Javascript "converting" that you need to do? Do you *know* the actual conversions necessary for all the JavaScript you have, or is it the case that you expect much of the Javascript to change but you don't know exactly how?

Comment: Sorry about the editing,IPAD safari,                           
>>>prebuilt with loads more support for native 
Is the IPAD safari same as desktop safari?

Comment: An example of what you want converted would be nice, with code

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools that will turn bad code into good code. Sounds like your company should either expect you to spend a lot of time learning how to code to standards or higher some contractor that knows their stuff and rewrite it in a percentage of the time.

If your code is using a lot of ActiveX stuff, you might be in for a shocker that Safari/Firefox/Chrome will not be able to do certain things.

Comment: When you develop large scale J2ee app, sometimes the requirements force you to write bad code... this is not the issue, I can supply some examples - can you tell me if there is a difference between desktop version of safari and ipad version of safari?